# img getting a 404 error when trying to load png logo in react

Tags: reactjs, vite

i am trying to load a logo in my navbar with a png file but it is returning a 404 error. i am loading the same file in my header which is working just fine.

[file tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TqSvh.png)

navbar component(which is throwing the 404 error with png) / index.html(which is loading the png just fine) -

```js
import {  Stack } from '@mui/material'
import React from 'react'
import { logo } from '../utils/constants'
import { SearchBar } from './index'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'

const Navbar = () => {

  return (
    <Stack
    direction='row'
    p={2}
    alignItems='center'
    sx={{ backgroundColor: "#000", position: 'sticky', top: 0,
    justifyContent: 'space-between', zIndex:'999'
     }} >
      <Link to="/" sx={{display: 'flex',
        alignItems:"center"}}>
        <img src={logo} alt="logo" height={45}/>
      </Link>
      <SearchBar/>
    </Stack>
  )
}

export default Navbar
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/svg+xml" href="./src/assets/play.png" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link
    rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700&display=swap"
    />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons"
    />
    <title>Plus Tube</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script type="module" src="/src/main.jsx"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

my export from constants file -

```js
export const logo = "../assets/play.png";
```